# param is missing or the value is empty: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, activerecord, postman

I'm using [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) to test my API and I'm getting the error `param is missing or the value is empty: user` when making a call to `http://localhost:3000/users.json` to create a new user. All the parameters seem to be ok.

I set this in my application controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

My controller method is the basic scaffold generated method:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here's a screenshot of what I'm doing in Postman.

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on "making a call to http://localhost:3000/users.json" - can you give us the params you are POSTing to that?

Comment: Also, are you sure you can send a request directly to `users.json` - surely it would be a different path?

Comment: Updated the question with a screen shot of what I'm doing in postman. @RichPeck, I'm pretty sure I can. I also have a path to it set up as signup but that straight up gives me an error when I POST to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that my parameters weren't wrapped up as a `user` object. For instance, in my case, I would have to change the parameter:

```
username
```

For:

```
user[username]
```

Doing that for all parameters made the test work.

Comment: Could you be so kind and edit your answer with a complete example? Thx in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want me to clear up? What am I missing? I thought that my question combined with my answer would be enough.

Comment: Ok, no problem. If there's something still amiss just comment.